# Access variables in admin/controller, from catalog/template - opencart

Tags: controller, opencart, admin

Is it possible to access variables saved in admin settings from catalog templates.
From `admin/controller/extension/theme/themename.php` in `catalog/view/theme/themename/template/common/header.tpl`.
Say I want to access `List Description Limit` [- image link -](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9mPN.png) value in `themename.php`, from the `header.tpl` like `<?php echo List Description Limit; ?>`?

**Controller files:**
admin/controller/extension/theme/theme_default.php

```
class ControllerExtensionThemeThemeDefault extends Controller {
private $error = array();

public function index() {
    $this->load->language('extension/theme/theme_default');

    $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));

    $this->load->model('setting/setting');

    if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validate()) {
        $this->model_setting_setting->editSetting('theme_default', $this->request->post, $this->request->get['store_id']);

        $this->session->data['success'] = $this->language->get('text_success');

        $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('extension/extension', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&type=theme', true));
    }

    $data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');

    $data['text_edit'] = $this->language->get('text_edit');
    $data['text_enabled'] = $this->language->get('text_enabled');
    $data['text_disabled'] = $this->language->get('text_disabled');
    $data['text_product'] = $this->language->get('text_product');
    $data['text_image'] = $this->language->get('text_image');
    $data['text_general'] = $this->language->get('text_general');

    $data['entry_directory'] = $this->language->get('entry_directory');
    $data['entry_status'] = $this->language->get('entry_status');       
    $data['entry_product_limit'] = $this->language->get('entry_product_limit');
    $data['entry_product_description_length'] = $this->language->get('entry_product_description_length');
    $data['entry_image_category'] = $this->language->get('entry_image_category');
    $data['entry_image_thumb'] = $this->language->get('entry_image_thumb');
    $data['entry_image_popup'] = $this->language->get('entry_image_popup');
    $data['entry_image_product'] = $this->language->get('entry_image_product');
    $data['entry_image_additional'] = $this->language->get('entry_image_additional');
    $data['entry_image_related'] = $this->language->get('entry_image_related');
    $data['entry_image_compare'] = $this->language->get('entry_image_compare');
    $data['entry_image_wishlist'] = $this->language->get('entry_image_wishlist');
    $data['entry_image_cart'] = $this->language->get('entry_image_cart');
    $data['entry_image_location'] = $this->language->get('entry_image_location');
    $data['entry_width'] = $this->language->get('entry_width');
    $data['entry_height'] = $this->language->get('entry_height');

    $data['help_product_limit'] = $this->language->get('help_product_limit');
    $data['help_product_description_length'] = $this->language->get('help_product_description_length');
    $data['help_directory'] = $this->language->get('help_directory');

    $data['button_save'] = $this->language->get('button_save');
    $data['button_cancel'] = $this->language->get('button_cancel');

    if (isset($this->error['warning'])) {
        $data['error_warning'] = $this->error['warning'];
    } else {
        $data['error_warning'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->error['product_limit'])) {
        $data['error_product_limit'] = $this->error['product_limit'];
    } else {
        $data['error_product_limit'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->error['product_description_length'])) {
        $data['error_product_description_length'] = $this->error['product_description_length'];
    } else {
        $data['error_product_description_length'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->error['image_category'])) {
        $data['error_image_category'] = $this->error['image_category'];
    } else {
        $data['error_image_category'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->error['image_thumb'])) {
        $data['error_image_thumb'] = $this->error['image_thumb'];
    } else {
        $data['error_image_thumb'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->error['image_popup'])) {
        $data['error_image_popup'] = $this->error['image_popup'];
    } else {
        $data['error_image_popup'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->error['image_product'])) {
        $data['error_image_product'] = $this->error['image_product'];
    } else {
        $data['error_image_product'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->error['image_additional'])) {
        $data['error_image_additional'] = $this->error['image_additional'];
    } else {
        $data['error_image_additional'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->error['image_related'])) {
        $data['error_image_related'] = $this->error['image_related'];
    } else {
        $data['error_image_related'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->error['image_compare'])) {
        $data['error_image_compare'] = $this->error['image_compare'];
    } else {
        $data['error_image_compare'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->error['image_wishlist'])) {
        $data['error_image_wishlist'] = $this->error['image_wishlist'];
    } else {
        $data['error_image_wishlist'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->error['image_cart'])) {
        $data['error_image_cart'] = $this->error['image_cart'];
    } else {
        $data['error_image_cart'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->error['image_location'])) {
        $data['error_image_location'] = $this->error['image_location'];
    } else {
        $data['error_image_location'] = '';
    }

    $data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

    $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
        'text' => $this->language->get('text_home'),
        'href' => $this->url->link('common/dashboard', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], true)
    );

    $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
        'text' => $this->language->get('text_extension'),
        'href' => $this->url->link('extension/extension', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&type=theme', true)
    );

    $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
        'text' => $this->language->get('heading_title'),
        'href' => $this->url->link('extension/theme/theme_default', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&store_id=' . $this->request->get['store_id'], true)
    );

    $data['action'] = $this->url->link('extension/theme/theme_default', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&store_id=' . $this->request->get['store_id'], true);

    $data['cancel'] = $this->url->link('extension/extension', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&type=theme', true);

    if (isset($this->request->get['store_id']) && ($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST')) {
        $setting_info = $this->model_setting_setting->getSetting('theme_default', $this->request->get['store_id']);
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['theme_default_directory'])) {
        $data['theme_default_directory'] = $this->request->post['theme_default_directory'];
    } elseif (isset($setting_info['theme_default_directory'])) {
        $data['theme_default_directory'] = $setting_info['theme_default_directory'];
    } else {
        $data['theme_default_directory'] = 'default';
    }       

    $data['directories'] = array();

    $directories = glob(DIR_CATALOG . 'view/theme/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);

    foreach ($directories as $directory) {
        $data['directories'][] = basename($directory);
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['theme_default_product_limit'])) {
        $data['theme_default_product_limit'] = $this->request->post['theme_default_product_limit'];
    } elseif (isset($setting_info['theme_default_product_limit'])) {
        $data['theme_default_product_limit'] = $setting_info['theme_default_product_limit'];
    } else {
        $data['theme_default_product_limit'] = 15;
    }       

    if (isset($this->request->post['theme_default_status'])) {
        $data['theme_default_status'] = $this->request->post['theme_default_status'];
    } elseif (isset($setting_info['theme_default_status'])) {
        $data['theme_default_status'] = $this->config->get('theme_default_status');
    } else {
        $data['theme_default_status'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['theme_default_product_description_length'])) {
        $data['theme_default_product_description_length'] = $this->request->post['theme_default_product_description_length'];
    } elseif (isset($setting_info['theme_default_product_description_length'])) {
        $data['theme_default_product_description_length'] = $this->config->get('theme_default_product_description_length');
    } else {
        $data['theme_default_product_description_length'] = 100;
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['theme_default_image_category_width'])) {
        $data['theme_default_image_category_width'] = $this->request->post['theme_default_image_category_width'];
    } elseif (isset($setting_info['theme_default_image_category_width'])) {
        $data['theme_default_image_category_width'] = $this->config->get('theme_default_image_category_width');
    } else {
        $data['theme_default_image_category_width'] = 80;       
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['theme_default_image_category_height'])) {
        $data['theme_default_image_category_height'] = $this->request->post['theme_default_image_category_height'];
    } elseif (isset($setting_info['theme_default_image_category_height'])) {
        $data['theme_default_image_category_height'] = $this->config->get('theme_default_image_category_height');
    } else {
        $data['theme_default_image_category_height'] = 80;
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['theme_default_image_thumb_width'])) {
        $data['theme_default_image_thumb_width'] = $this->request->post['theme_default_image_thumb_width'];
    } elseif (isset($setting_info['theme_default_image_thumb_width'])) {
        $data['theme_default_image_thumb_width'] = $this->config->get('theme_default_image_thumb_width');
    } else {
        $data['theme_default_image_thumb_width'] = 228;
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['theme_default_image_thumb_height'])) {
        $data['theme_default_image_thumb_height'] = $this->request->post['theme_default_image_thumb_height'];
    } elseif (isset($setting_info['theme_default_image_thumb_height'])) {
        $data['theme_default_image_thumb_height'] = $this->config->get('theme_default_image_thumb_height');
    } else {
        $data['theme_default_image_thumb_height'] = 228;        
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['theme_default_image_popup_width'])) {
        $data['theme_default_image_popup_width'] = $this->request->post['theme_default_image_popup_width'];
    } elseif (isset($setting_info['theme_default_image_popup_width'])) {
        $data['theme_default_image_popup_width'] = $this->config->get('theme_default_image_popup_width');
    } else {
        $data['theme_default_image_popup_width'] = 500;
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['theme_default_image_popup_height'])) {
        $data['theme_default_image_popup_height'] = $this->request->post['theme_default_image_popup_height'];
    } elseif (isset($setting_info['theme_default_image_popup_height'])) {
        $data['theme_default_image_popup_height'] = $this->config->get('theme_default_image_popup_height');
    } else {
        $data['theme_default_image_popup_height'] = 500;
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['theme_default_image_product_width'])) {
        $data['theme_default_image_product_width'] = $this->request->post['theme_default_image_product_width'];
    } elseif (isset($setting_info['theme_default_image_product_width'])) {
        $data['theme_default_image_product_width'] = $this->config->get('theme_default_image_product_width');
    } else {
        $data['theme_default_image_product_width'] = 228;
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['theme_default_image_product_height'])) {
        $data['theme_default_image_product_height'] = $this->request->post['theme_default_image_product_height'];
    } elseif (isset($setting_info['theme_default_image_product_height'])) {
        $data['theme_default_image_product_height'] = $this->config->get('theme_default_image_product_height');
    } else {
        $data['theme_default_image_product_height'] = 228;
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['theme_default_image_additional_width'])) {
        $data['theme_default_image_additional_width'] = $this->request->post['theme_default_image_additional_width'];
    } elseif (isset($setting_info['theme_default_image_additional_width'])) {
        $data['theme_default_image_additional_width'] = $this->config->get('theme_default_image_additional_width');
    } else {
        $data['theme_default_image_additional_width'] = 74;
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['theme_default_image_additional_height'])) {
        $data['theme_default_image_additional_height'] = $this->request->post['theme_default_image_additional_height'];
    } elseif (isset($setting_info['theme_default_image_additional_height'])) {
        $data['theme_default_image_additional_height'] = $this->config->get('theme_default_image_additional_height');
    } else {
        $data['theme_default_image_additional_height'] = 74;
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['theme_default_image_related_width'])) {
        $data['theme_default_image_related_width'] = $this->request->post['theme_default_image_related_width'];
    } elseif (isset($setting_info['theme_default_image_related_width'])) {
        $data['theme_default_image_related_width'] = $this->config->get('theme_default_image_related_width');
    } else {
        $data['theme_default_image_related_width'] = 80;
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['theme_default_image_related_height'])) {
        $data['theme_default_image_related_height'] = $this->request->post['theme_default_image_related_height'];
    } elseif (isset($setting_info['theme_default_image_related_height'])) {
        $data['theme_default_image_related_height'] = $this->config->get('theme_default_image_related_height');
    } else {
        $data['theme_default_image_related_height'] = 80;
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['theme_default_image_compare_width'])) {
        $data['theme_default_image_compare_width'] = $this->request->post['theme_default_image_compare_width'];
    } elseif (isset($setting_info['theme_default_image_compare_width'])) {
        $data['theme_default_image_compare_width'] = $this->config->get('theme_default_image_compare_width');
    } else {
        $data['theme_default_image_compare_width'] = 90;
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['theme_default_image_compare_height'])) {
        $data['theme_default_image_compare_height'] = $this->request->post['theme_default_image_compare_height'];
    } elseif (isset($setting_info['theme_default_image_compare_height'])) {
        $data['theme_default_image_compare_height'] = $this->config->get('theme_default_image_compare_height');
    } else {
        $data['theme_default_image_compare_height'] = 90;
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['theme_default_image_wishlist_width'])) {
        $data['theme_default_image_wishlist_width'] = $this->request->post['theme_default_image_wishlist_width'];
    } elseif (isset($setting_info['theme_default_image_wishlist_width'])) {
        $data['theme_default_image_wishlist_width'] = $this->config->get('theme_default_image_wishlist_width');
    } else {
        $data['theme_default_image_wishlist_width'] = 47;
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['theme_default_image_wishlist_height'])) {
        $data['theme_default_image_wishlist_height'] = $this->request->post['theme_default_image_wishlist_height'];
    } elseif (isset($setting_info['theme_default_image_wishlist_height'])) {
        $data['theme_default_image_wishlist_height'] = $this->config->get('theme_default_image_wishlist_height');
    } else {
        $data['theme_default_image_wishlist_height'] = 47;
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['theme_default_image_cart_width'])) {
        $data['theme_default_image_cart_width'] = $this->request->post['theme_default_image_cart_width'];
    } elseif (isset($setting_info['theme_default_image_cart_width'])) {
        $data['theme_default_image_cart_width'] = $this->config->get('theme_default_image_cart_width');
    } else {
        $data['theme_default_image_cart_width'] = 47;
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['theme_default_image_cart_height'])) {
        $data['theme_default_image_cart_height'] = $this->request->post['theme_default_image_cart_height'];
    } elseif (isset($setting_info['theme_default_image_cart_height'])) {
        $data['theme_default_image_cart_height'] = $this->config->get('theme_default_image_cart_height');
    } else {
        $data['theme_default_image_cart_height'] = 47;
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['theme_default_image_location_width'])) {
        $data['theme_default_image_location_width'] = $this->request->post['theme_default_image_location_width'];
    } elseif (isset($setting_info['theme_default_image_location_width'])) {
        $data['theme_default_image_location_width'] = $this->config->get('theme_default_image_location_width');
    } else {
        $data['theme_default_image_location_width'] = 268;
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['theme_default_image_location_height'])) {
        $data['theme_default_image_location_height'] = $this->request->post['theme_default_image_location_height'];
    } elseif (isset($setting_info['theme_default_image_location_height'])) {
        $data['theme_default_image_location_height'] = $this->config->get('theme_default_image_location_height');
    } else {
        $data['theme_default_image_location_height'] = 50;
    }

    $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');
    $data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
    $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');

    $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('extension/theme/theme_default', $data));
}

protected function validate() {
    if (!$this->user->hasPermission('modify', 'extension/theme/theme_default')) {
        $this->error['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_permission');
    }

    if (!$this->request->post['theme_default_product_limit']) {
        $this->error['product_limit'] = $this->language->get('error_limit');
    }

    if (!$this->request->post['theme_default_product_description_length']) {
        $this->error['product_description_length'] = $this->language->get('error_limit');
    }

    if (!$this->request->post['theme_default_image_category_width'] || !$this->request->post['theme_default_image_category_height']) {
        $this->error['image_category'] = $this->language->get('error_image_category');
    }

    if (!$this->request->post['theme_default_image_thumb_width'] || !$this->request->post['theme_default_image_thumb_height']) {
        $this->error['image_thumb'] = $this->language->get('error_image_thumb');
    }

    if (!$this->request->post['theme_default_image_popup_width'] || !$this->request->post['theme_default_image_popup_height']) {
        $this->error['image_popup'] = $this->language->get('error_image_popup');
    }

    if (!$this->request->post['theme_default_image_product_width'] || !$this->request->post['theme_default_image_product_height']) {
        $this->error['image_product'] = $this->language->get('error_image_product');
    }

    if (!$this->request->post['theme_default_image_additional_width'] || !$this->request->post['theme_default_image_additional_height']) {
        $this->error['image_additional'] = $this->language->get('error_image_additional');
    }

    if (!$this->request->post['theme_default_image_related_width'] || !$this->request->post['theme_default_image_related_height']) {
        $this->error['image_related'] = $this->language->get('error_image_related');
    }

    if (!$this->request->post['theme_default_image_compare_width'] || !$this->request->post['theme_default_image_compare_height']) {
        $this->error['image_compare'] = $this->language->get('error_image_compare');
    }

    if (!$this->request->post['theme_default_image_wishlist_width'] || !$this->request->post['theme_default_image_wishlist_height']) {
        $this->error['image_wishlist'] = $this->language->get('error_image_wishlist');
    }

    if (!$this->request->post['theme_default_image_cart_width'] || !$this->request->post['theme_default_image_cart_height']) {
        $this->error['image_cart'] = $this->language->get('error_image_cart');
    }

    if (!$this->request->post['theme_default_image_location_width'] || !$this->request->post['theme_default_image_location_height']) {
        $this->error['image_location'] = $this->language->get('error_image_location');
    }

    return !$this->error;
}
```

}

catalog/controller/common/header.php

```
class ControllerCommonHeader extends Controller {
public function index() {
    // Analytics
    $this->load->model('extension/extension');


    $this->load->model('setting/setting');
    if (isset($this->request->get['store_id']) && ($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST')) {
        $setting_info = $this->model_setting_setting->getSetting('theme_default', $this->request->get['store_id']);
    }
    if (isset($setting_info['theme_default_product_description_length'])) {
        $data['theme_default_product_description_length'] = $this->config->get('theme_default_product_description_length');
    }



    $data['analytics'] = array();

    $analytics = $this->model_extension_extension->getExtensions('analytics');

    foreach ($analytics as $analytic) {
        if ($this->config->get($analytic['code'] . '_status')) {
            $data['analytics'][] = $this->load->controller('extension/analytics/' . $analytic['code'], $this->config->get($analytic['code'] . '_status'));
        }
    }

    if ($this->request->server['HTTPS']) {
        $server = $this->config->get('config_ssl');
    } else {
        $server = $this->config->get('config_url');
    }

    if (is_file(DIR_IMAGE . $this->config->get('config_icon'))) {
        $this->document->addLink($server . 'image/' . $this->config->get('config_icon'), 'icon');
    }

    $data['title'] = $this->document->getTitle();

    $data['base'] = $server;
    $data['description'] = $this->document->getDescription();
    $data['keywords'] = $this->document->getKeywords();
    $data['links'] = $this->document->getLinks();
    $data['styles'] = $this->document->getStyles();
    $data['scripts'] = $this->document->getScripts();
    $data['lang'] = $this->language->get('code');
    $data['direction'] = $this->language->get('direction');

    $data['name'] = $this->config->get('config_name');

    if (is_file(DIR_IMAGE . $this->config->get('config_logo'))) {
        $data['logo'] = $server . 'image/' . $this->config->get('config_logo');
    } else {
        $data['logo'] = '';
    }

    $this->load->language('common/header');

    $data['text_home'] = $this->language->get('text_home');

    // Wishlist
    if ($this->customer->isLogged()) {
        $this->load->model('account/wishlist');

        $data['text_wishlist'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_wishlist'), $this->model_account_wishlist->getTotalWishlist());
    } else {
        $data['text_wishlist'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_wishlist'), (isset($this->session->data['wishlist']) ? count($this->session->data['wishlist']) : 0));
    }

    $data['text_shopping_cart'] = $this->language->get('text_shopping_cart');
    $data['text_logged'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_logged'), $this->url->link('account/account', '', true), $this->customer->getFirstName(), $this->url->link('account/logout', '', true));

    $data['text_account'] = $this->language->get('text_account');
    $data['text_register'] = $this->language->get('text_register');
    $data['text_login'] = $this->language->get('text_login');
    $data['text_order'] = $this->language->get('text_order');
    $data['text_transaction'] = $this->language->get('text_transaction');
    $data['text_download'] = $this->language->get('text_download');
    $data['text_logout'] = $this->language->get('text_logout');
    $data['text_checkout'] = $this->language->get('text_checkout');
    $data['text_category'] = $this->language->get('text_category');
    $data['text_all'] = $this->language->get('text_all');

    $data['home'] = $this->url->link('common/home');
    $data['wishlist'] = $this->url->link('account/wishlist', '', true);
    $data['logged'] = $this->customer->isLogged();
    $data['account'] = $this->url->link('account/account', '', true);
    $data['register'] = $this->url->link('account/register', '', true);
    $data['login'] = $this->url->link('account/login', '', true);
    $data['order'] = $this->url->link('account/order', '', true);
    $data['transaction'] = $this->url->link('account/transaction', '', true);
    $data['download'] = $this->url->link('account/download', '', true);
    $data['logout'] = $this->url->link('account/logout', '', true);
    $data['shopping_cart'] = $this->url->link('checkout/cart');
    $data['checkout'] = $this->url->link('checkout/checkout', '', true);
    $data['contact'] = $this->url->link('information/contact');
    $data['telephone'] = $this->config->get('config_telephone');

    // Menu
    $this->load->model('catalog/category');

    $this->load->model('catalog/product');

    $data['categories'] = array();

    $categories = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories(0);

    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        if ($category['top']) {
            // Level 2
            $children_data = array();

            $children = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($category['category_id']);

            foreach ($children as $child) {
                $filter_data = array(
                    'filter_category_id'  => $child['category_id'],
                    'filter_sub_category' => true
                );

                $children_data[] = array(
                    'name'  => $child['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($filter_data) . ')' : ''),
                    'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $child['category_id'])
                );
            }

            // Level 1
            $data['categories'][] = array(
                'name'     => $category['name'],
                'children' => $children_data,
                'column'   => $category['column'] ? $category['column'] : 1,
                'href'     => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'])
            );
        }
    }

    $data['language'] = $this->load->controller('common/language');
    $data['currency'] = $this->load->controller('common/currency');
    $data['search'] = $this->load->controller('common/search');
    $data['cart'] = $this->load->controller('common/cart');

    // For page specific css
    if (isset($this->request->get['route'])) {
        if (isset($this->request->get['product_id'])) {
            $class = '-' . $this->request->get['product_id'];
        } elseif (isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
            $class = '-' . $this->request->get['path'];
        } elseif (isset($this->request->get['manufacturer_id'])) {
            $class = '-' . $this->request->get['manufacturer_id'];
        } elseif (isset($this->request->get['information_id'])) {
            $class = '-' . $this->request->get['information_id'];
        } else {
            $class = '';
        }

        $data['class'] = str_replace('/', '-', $this->request->get['route']) . $class;
    } else {
        $data['class'] = 'common-home';
    }

    return $this->load->view('common/header', $data);
}
```

}

catalog/view/theme/default/common/header.tpl
I did echo $theme_default_product_description_length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to edit your theme file: `catalog\view\theme\themename\template\common\header.tpl` and its controller file `catalog\controller\common\header.php` to display the data. To get the data, you can look at the controller file that handles the page in your screenshot:

`\admin\controller\extension\theme\theme_default.php`

**EDIT**

After testing, an easier approach is a single line (you can remove the other code I gave you - sorry about that)

```
$data['theme_default_product_description_length'] = $this->config->get('theme_default_product_description_length');
```

You should now be able to use `echo $theme_default_product_description_length;` on your `header.tpl` file

It's always useful to try and find the place where it's used, look at how the data is stored / retrieved and then apply the code to your desired modification

Comment: That is what I did but for whatever reason I get an `Undefined variable: theme_default_product_description_length in /catalog/view/theme/default/template/common/header.tpl` error when I try to `echo` it, what the problem could be? Thanks

Comment: If you've tried something, you should add your code that's not working. Please paste your controller file's php code in your question. A quick glance at the example shows that there `$data['theme_default_product_description_length']` would not be initiated with a value if the setting value is not pulled correctly. Having your code will help troubleshoot

Comment: **I replaced**  
`if (isset($this->request->get['store_id']) && ($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST')) { $setting_info = $this->model_setting_setting->getSetting('theme_default', $this->request->get['store_id']); }`  
**with**  
`if ($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') { $setting_info = $this->model_setting_setting->getSetting('theme_default', $this->request->get['store_id']); }`  
So it's seems it won't pass the `isset($this->request->get['store_id'])` check for whatever reason, what that might be?

Comment: @AlexTofan I've updated my answer after testing on my test site, the updated solution is easier to implement and works

Comment: That worked great! Thanks! Is it possible to make it globally available in all `.tpl` files or I need to edit every `controller` and add that line? @Daniel

Comment: From what I understand of OpenCart, you would have to add it to each controller file. You can also try adding it to the session variable which should make it available to all controllers but you'd still have to assign it. I may be wrong here though.

Comment: What you could do is wrap the header's display of the `theme_default_product_description_length` value in a span or div with an HTML `id` value and then use jQuery to grab it when you need it, that should be simpler than adding it to every controller since every page uses the `header.tpl` file

Comment: I want to use it in `.tpl` files as native variables are used, that was an example but I want to create custom variables to use across the template files. Another way would be to output a JSON object in the header I guess.